# Python Twisted/Reactor can't send the message to server/client

Tags: python, server, client, twisted, p2p

I'm trying to make a P2P based message sender with twisted, but unfortunately I can't send my message from the client to get the connected IPs. For example the startProtocol() function is called, but the data in not transferred to the server. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Server

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from random import randint


class Server(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = set()
        print("Server initialized")

    def datagramRecieved(self, datagram, addr):
        datagram = datagram.decode("utf-8")
        print("Datagram recieved"+datagram)
        if datagram == "ready":
            adresses = "\n".join([str(x) for x in self.clients])

            self.transport.write(adresses.encode('utf-8'), addr)
            self.clients.add(addr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenUDP(9999, Server())
    reactor.run()
```

Client

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from random import randint


class Client(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        if host == "localhost":
            host = "127.0.0.1"
        self.id = host, port
        self.address = None
        self.server = '127.0.0.1', 9999
        print("Working on id:", self.id)

    def startProtocol(self):
        print("Called startProtocol")
        self.transport.write("ready".encode("utf-8"), self.server)

    def datagramRecieved(self, datagaram, addr):
        datagaram = datagaram.decode('utf-8')

        if addr == self.server:
            print("Choose a client from these\n", datagaram)
            addresses = datagaram.split('\n')
            self.address = input("write host:"), int(input("write port"))
            reactor.callInThread(self.send_message)
        else:
            print(addr, ":", datagaram)

    def send_message(self):
        while True:
            self.transport.write(
                input("Uzeneted:").encode('utf-8'), self.address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = randint(1000, 5000)
    reactor.listenUDP(port, Client('localhost', port))
    reactor.run()
```